# VBA Excel - Replace Enter key with Alt+ Enter

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I am trying to replace <kbd>Enter</kbd> key with <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd> so that I can write multiline in cells with ease.

I have seen that there is a function `Application.OnKey` and `Application.SendKeys` and I wanted to use those something like this:

```
Application.OnKey "~" , Application.SendKeys("%~")
```

But where do I place those? Or any other ideas?

Comment: The problem is that you probably first need to undo the enter, then do the alt-enter. And the issue is that if you are in the middle of a cell the undo will not be undo. I doubt this will work

Comment: And do you want to replace Ctrl+ENTER by Ctrl+Alt+ENTER too?

Comment: Dominique, i just want to replace Enter. And @Andreas i think that there could be a way with temporary variables and location to remember where the enter happend and then return to add the carriage return and get cell in focus but I personally think that kind of effort would not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I agree with @Andreas, this is unlikely to work using these methods.

This is what I tried: I made a button Button1 and in its click method I assign the Enter key to send Alt-Enter as you suggest in the question:

```
Sub Button1_onClick()

    Call Application.OnKey("~", "SendAltEnter")

End Sub

Sub SendAltEnter()

    Application.SendKeys ("%~")
    
End Sub
```

This does in fact re-route the Enter key, but apparently the Alt-Enter results in another call to the method for the "Enter" part of "Alt-Enter" -- it results in an infinite loop the first time you hit enter after having clicked the button, and you have to restart your Excel application to clean it up.

I also tried this, simply using another key near Enter, namely # (at least on German keyboards) which you could hit instead of Alt-Enter:

```
Sub Button1_onClick()

    Call Application.OnKey("#", "SendAltEnter")

End Sub

Sub SendAltEnter()

    Application.SendKeys ("%~")
    
End Sub
```

The key '#' is intercepted, but not if you are in input mode in a cell, only if the focus is somewhere in the worksheet.

I think you'll have to do this outside of Excel using a keyboard remapping tool for Windows. I quickly found https://www.howtogeek.com/710290/how-to-remap-any-key-or-shortcut-on-windows-10/ by googling but know nothing about it or if it is legit or not.

Comment: I also considered key remapping, but that excel would be used by more people that don't really have time to remap. And thank you for trying ^^ .

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert a carriage return instead?

Comment: That would be a good ideea but would defeat the purpose of using only one single key.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).